# Horizontal scroll doesn't work on mobile (android)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, scroll

i've been building a fully horizontal webpage and it works like a charm on desktop, but it does not scroll on mobile, at least on android which is the only one I can test on.

Here's the live demo: http://escoladocaosdigital.com/projetos/mundovuca_mundobani/

Comment: Plz, mention the issue you are facing when using it on mobile because [it's working on both Android and IOS. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/slyNl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slyNl.png)

Comment: Actually it is not scrolling on my actual mobile phone, devtools is indeed working. Thanks anyway.